# Access callback parameter to inner callback

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understanding this code.

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

a.forEach(i => {
  setTimeout(i => {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
});
```

Why its giving output something like this:

```
5 times: undefined
```

I know `javascript` executes code asynchronously and schedule `setTimeout` function, When the iteration is stopped last value of `i` is undefined but why undefined.
Does in `javascript` we can't access the scope of the outer callback parameter?

Comment: `i` of `setTimeout` is shadowing `i` of `forEach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just standard shadowing.

Consider the following code:

```js
let x = "outer";
console.log(x);
{
    let x = "inner";
    console.log(x);
}
console.log(x);
```

The inner block can't access the outer `x` because it has declared a local variable of the same name.

Similarly, in your code there are two variables called `i`:

```
    a.forEach(i => {
        setTimeout(i => {
```

The only difference is that they're function parameters, not declared with `let`. Apart from that they work the same way: The inner `i` shadows the outer `i`, preventing access. To fix this, simply remove the inner `i`. `setTimeout` doesn't pass any useful arguments to the callback anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `i` in `setTimeout`

```js
let a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a.forEach((i) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your inner callback has a parameter named `i`, which shadows the outer `i`.

`setTimeout()` doesn't pass any parameters to its callback, so the inner `i` is `undefined`.

To use a parameter or variable from the outer callback, simply use it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use make use of the third parameter to `setTimeout`. All the parameters added after the `delay` will be passed as parameters to the function inside `setTimeout`

This is the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Syntax):

```
setTimeout(func[, delay, param1, param2, ...])
```

Here, `param1, param2` etc are passed as parameters to `func`

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.forEach(i => {
  setTimeout(value => {
    console.log(value);
  }, 1000, i);
});
```

This is useful if you have the function defined separately and cannot take closure over the `i` of `forEach` callback

```js
function callback(value) {
  console.log(value)
}

let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
a.forEach(i => {
  setTimeout(callback, 1000, i);
});
```

Comment: Clever alternative, definitely an interesting solution

Comment: @briosheje definitely, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: You never really need that. You can always just wrap another anonymous function around it: `a.forEach(i => { setTimeout(() => callback(i), 1000); })`. Technically speaking the third parameter to `setTimeout` is 100% redundant.